# creating a rectangle in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to draw two rectangles in a picture box in VB (for school) but it does not seem to work at all

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim paper As Graphics()
    paper = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
    Dim pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)

    paper.DrawRectangle(pen, 10, 10, 100, 50)
    paper.DrawRectangle(pen, 10, 75, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the paint event of the PixtureBox.

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses on the line `Dim paper As Graphics()`. It should be a `Graphics` object, not an array of `Graphics` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't paint in the Paint event it will not persist.

```
Private Sub Picturebox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.PaintEventArgs) Handles Picturebox1.Paint
  Using pen As New Pen(Color.Black)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 10, 10, 100, 50)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 10, 75, 100, 100)
  End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: you should override the OnPaint method instead. it ensures the graphics will be drawn in the same frame as the control's default graphics object. MSDN: Control.Paint Event, and MSDN: Control.OnPaint Method. and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That does not apply to this post.

Comment: it applies to every post... too bad, not enough rep for downvote.